# What is the probability of being dealt four of a kind with restriction

Tags: probability

How to solve this problem

What is the probability of being dealt four of a kind in poker (i.e. 52 deck with 5 cards per hand) with the restriction that the four of kind is only in this group {10,J,Q,K,A}.

Without restriction, we get

$$
P(\text{four of a kind}) = \frac{ {13\choose 1} {48\choose 1}  }{52\choose 5} = 0.024
$$

I'm guessing that we have 13 cases for a four of kind or $P(\text{all of four of kind}) = 13*0.024$, therefore,  $P(\text{four of kind for}{10,J,Q,K,A}) = 4*.024 =0.096$. Is this correct?

Comment: No.  While true, we have 13 cases for four of a kind hands... that $13$ *already appeared in the calculations* in the form of the $\binom{13}{1}$ in the numerator.  You do not need to use $13$ again...  If you want it to specifically be a four of a kind of a 10,J,Q,K, or A... rather than $13$ in the numerator of the original calculation... all you have to do is replace it with $5$ as there are only five ranks you are interested in allowing as your four of a kind.

Comment: Worded another way... the probability of a *specific* type of four-of-a-kind would be $48/\binom{52}{5}$... (*that is to say, the probability of four $2$'s would be $48/\binom{52}{5}$ just like the probability of four $8$'s would also be $48/\binom{52}{5}$ etc...*).  The probability of a four of a kind of *any* type would be $13$ times $48/\binom{52}{5}$... and of your specific restricted types as $5$ times that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but your answer without restriction is not correct. It evaluates to $\dfrac{1}{4165} \approx 0.00024$. Now given we can choose four of a kind from only $5$ ranks $(10, J, Q, K, A)$ instead of $13$ ranks, the probability should be,

$P(\text{four of a kind} \cap (10, J, Q, K, A)) = \displaystyle  \frac{ {5\choose 1} {48\choose 1}  }{52\choose 5} = \frac{1}{10829}$

Or in other words, it is $ \dfrac{1}{4165} \times \dfrac{5}{13}$

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.  The factor of $\binom{13}1$ in the expression you give reflects the fact that there are $13$ ways you can chose the rank of the quadruplicated card.  Since we now only have $5$ (not $4$) choices, this should be replaced by $\binom 51$:   $$ \frac{ {5\choose 1} {48\choose 1}  }{52\choose 5}$$